# Allocating resources for SQL Server instances -dba

Tags: database-administration

I have a question regarding allocating resources for SQL Server 2008 R2. We a have physical server Windows 2008 R2 with three installations of SQL Server 2008 R2 for Production, test and development. The server has 64GB of RAM and 24 cores. If we want to allocate specific amount of resources to specific instance, can we do it? For instance, we want allocate 32 GB and 12 cores for production instance, and 12 GB and 6 cores each for test and development.

Because all three instances are on the same physical server, we do not want the test and development instances to consume more resources than we want them to. Is there a way to set it in the server or in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options. The three options I see are:

(1) use a VM for each server on the same physical machine and allocate resources to the VMs as you see fit.

(2) use sql server resource governor (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/04/sql-server-simple-example-to-configure-resource-governor-introduction-to-resource-governor/)

With this you can setup resource consumption by user. So for your test server, just setup its users with a lower resource allocation.

(3) in sql server you can also set the max memory of an instance in sys.configurations using sp_configure. For CPU you could try experimenting with affinity mask in a test environment or assigning a specific CPU id range or NUMA node id range to the instance. For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210585(v=sql.110).aspx

I would recommend always setting max server memory in any instance. I would not recommend messing with the affinity or CPU range settings without a lot of testing. Instead, for your case I would recommend using resource governor. This is bc it does not have the drawback of VMs, which themselves have overhead and thus use up some server resources. Also you can leave the CPU scheduling to the OS and server with resource governor. This option also gives you the most flexibility since you can limit resources by specific user, in case you ever need that.